# Updating MS Access Query?

Tags: ms-access, office365

I'm working an Access Database for my church's local cemetery. They wanted something free, and low-to-no-maintenance, and I didn't want to go with anything online.

So I've made a sample Access Database with the fields and a simple query, checking if the field is filled out, and searching for the field if it contains something. My only problem is that, since these people want something user-friendly and easy, I can't have them right-click, close, then double click on the query every time they update the search form and click the button. What's the best way to fix this?

Again, I want to not have to quit out of and re-open the query every time I update the search form

Example Search (using random names): Every first name contains "o": https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhvXi.png

Example output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/654qJ.png

Comment: Do the search in the form header and should the results in the form details.

Comment: You're most welcome. Do me a favor and upvote my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the search in the form header and show the results in the form details.